# How Can I insert "_id": { "$oid": "5ec796a7868d607e00f4b18d" } and "time": 1590137305745 into mysql table?

Tags: mysql

I want to insert below data into mysql table but I am confuse how to store the "_id" part and the "time" in the specified format.The data which I want to insert is below(Json format):

```
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5ec791d996d4b0e5085e5577"
  },
  "user_id": "2670599422982578",
  "amount": 1000,
  "coins_balance": 1000,
  "txn_type": "credit",
  "txn_info": "purchase",
  "action": "purchase",
  "time": 1590137305745
```

Comment: First you will need to tell us what the MySQL Table looks like, so please do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` and post the output into your question

Answer (score 0):

MySQL tables are column-oriented. So, create yourself an `oid` column rather than an `id` column, and insert `_id.$oid` into it, rather than trying to preserve the Javascript object structure.

Comment: I did it but how can store time in the given format?